# How to validate that a request comes from a valid page, Node

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I was using the referrer in the header, but I've learned that it's not reliable because it can be changed by the user easily.

What other alternatives do I have? I want to validate that a request to a server comes from a certain page, can this be accomplished at all?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Anything a browser can send, a scraper or hacker can send as well. You could use some kind of anti cross-request forgery token. But then still a malicious user could first request the page setting the token, then send a request to the second page along with the token.

Answer (score 0):

Laerion, I do not believe there is a reliable way to do this if you don't want to rely on Referrer. However you could put it behind a reverse proxy (nginx/varnish), or set some type of cookie to get this information. good luck.

Comment: The referrer isn't reliable either. What will a proxy or cookie change?

Comment: I was thinking you could use security tokens in your URI, but I just did some research and this isn't reliable either, especially because unique identifiers are often stripped by various services to ensure privacy. Sorry, I don't think there is a way to do this.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit difficult to do. I'm actually chatting with my client the possibility that the browser doesn't go directly to the API, but using a server in the middle and use OAuth or something like that. I hope to convince him, because I can't find another way (reliable) for this. Thank you guys!